# Build a graph with Gtk Vala?

Tags: plot, gtk, gtk3, vala

I googled and found no way to draw line plots or histogram via gtk from vala. Is there a ready-made solution to not write your own on cairo? I can't believe there's no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [Caroline](https://github.com/dcharles525/Caroline) or [LibDazzle Charts](https://gitlab.com/gavr123456789/vala-snippets/blob/master/Fast-Examples/DazzleChart/v.vala).
Gnome System Monitor also uses the LibDazzle to display graphs of CPU load.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Graph UI https://github.com/artemanufrij/graphui But I dont think it would be really helpful in your case. 
But I would suggest you stick with cairo.